# Efficient implementation of exponential of projector

Tags: quantum-gate, gate-synthesis

If I have an $n$ qubit system and a projector $P$ such as $P_0 = \left|0\right>^{\otimes n}\left<0\right|^{\otimes n}$ (as an example) on those qubits, **is there an efficient way to implement the unitary $e^{-i\theta P}$?**

In the specific example given, there is a simple but inefficient implementation in terms of exponentials of Paulis: $$P_0 = \sum_{j\in\left\lbrace0, 1\right\rbrace^n}\bigotimes_{k=1}^nZ_k^{j_k},$$ where $Z^1_k$ is the Pauli-$Z$ operator on qubit $k$ and $Z^0_k$ is the identity on qubit $k$. That is, the given projector is the sum over all possible permutations of identity and $Z$. As $Z$ and identities all commute, this can then be written as $$U_{P_0} = \prod_{j\in\left\lbrace0, 1\right\rbrace^n}e^{-i\theta\bigotimes_{k=1}^nZ_k^{j_k}}.$$ However, for $n$ qubits, this requires an exponential number of gates. Is there any way to improve upon this?

Funnily enough, using e.g. the [Reck](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.73.58) or [Clements](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.08788) scheme (in photonics), this appears to be trivial, as it's simply a phase on a single mode. However, to my knowledge, this doesn't count as it requires an expontial number of resources to recreate the evolution given by a unitary acting on $n$ qubits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With auxiliary qubits, you could construct a gate that is controlled on the $n$ qubits being $0$ to apply $X$ to the auxiliary. This can be done with polynomially many gates and auxiliaries.

Once you have that, you can apply contolled $e^{-i \theta}$ on any of the original $n$.

Then do all the uncomputation.